# Python. manipulating date/ time strings

Tags: python, date

I'm using SHARADAR/DAILY data . the dataset/ data frame looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpehM.png)

i need to write a piece of code that returns the latest marketcap value.

when i write the following code...

```
    trade_date = "2021-05-16"
    df2 = quandl.get_table('SHARADAR/DAILY', ticker='AAPL', date=trade_date)
    print(df2)
```

the result is empty an dataframe

```
Series([], Name: marketcap, dtype: object)
```

i need to do two things...

1. i need it to return a single value , not a dataframe, so that i can do arithmetic calculations with it.
2. I need to create a loop that checks.. if value is empty, try to get marketcap for "trade_date" minus one day which is "2021-05-15", else return marketcap. keep minus-ing one day until we get a non-blank/ non-zero market cap

   Empty DataFrame
   Columns: [ticker, date, lastupdated, ev, evebit, evebitda, marketcap, pb, pe, ps]
   Index: []

Answer (score 0):

mmmm
Use datetime and timedelta

```py
import datetime

date_you_want = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-05-07", "%Y-%m-%d").date() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

then you can get the date in the format you want

```
date_you_want.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

will give you "2020-04-30"